# NSTimer is Not stopping when double Click on a Button

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, nstimer

I have `NSTimer` to display an image after 2 seconds when i click on button. It is working fine when I Click on a Button, But the problem is When I double Click the Button the NSTimer is Not Stopping. Continuously it is displaying images(calling `NSTimer` method) without Clicking on the button for Next Time. How to stop the `NSTimer` when i double Click / more Clicks on that button at a time.

```
*This is my Code*

-(void)buttonClicked
{

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(timerClicked) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
imgviewtransparent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}


-(void)timerClicked
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil; 

}
```

Comment: And why do you think it would stop when you double click the button? The only thing that will happen is that your callback will be called as many times as you click the button... And the callback itself does not stop/invalidate the timer; it just schedules another one.

However, could you attach more code or the way you have linked your button events, please?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With double Click it will schedule timer twice.
You can create a `BOOL` property to avoid this if you want.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Define all your implementation

    //Set BOOL property to no at start
    self.isButtonClicked = NO; // You need to define this BOOL property as well.
}

-(void)buttonClicked {
    // Return if one click is already in process
    if (self.isButtonClicked) {
        return;
    }

    self.isButtonClicked = YES:
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self         
    selector:@selector(timerClicked) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    imgviewtransparent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}


-(void)timerClicked {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil; 
    self.isButtonClicked = NO;
}
```